# PTH drill diameter do the IPC take the pin distance in account?

Tags: pcb, pins, footprint, cad, ipc

I wonder if the IPC take the Pin distance tolerance in account for the drill diameter? (see p in pic). I can't find any guidelines for it anywhere.

Or is it just so that it's implicitly,common sense that the drill diameter shall be: pin tolerance distance + maximum pin diamter = minimum drill diameter?

That is what I would assume if there isn't any guidelines in any IPC?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://www.pcb-3d.com/knowledge-base/pth-dimensions/) is an indirect reference to the actual (for pay) IPC documents, but it appears it does not take pitch tolerances into account.

[image: Plated Through Hole Cutaway Image]

Minimum Hole Size is calculated according to equations below:

```
Minimum Hole Size = Maximum Lead Diameter + 0.25mm (for Level A of IPC-2222)
Minimum Hole Size = Maximum Lead Diameter + 0.20mm (for Level B of IPC-2222)
Minimum Hole Size = Maximum Lead Diameter + 0.15mm (for Level C of IPC-2222)
```

---

There is some compliance in the leads even close to the body, and the ends are certainly not guaranteed to not be bent a bit, so it's not as important as you might think.

Comment: Yes I've seen it and I also have access to latest IPC-2222.
However as you say it doesn't seem to take the pitch tolerances in account. Which I believe may be a problem for some radial components with thick leads that don't bend easy.

Answer (score 0):

IPC std is 0.2mm drill size over lead size +/-0.05mm depending on 3 classes of part and process.

http://www.ipc.org/committee/drafts/1-13_d_7251WD1.pdf

Comment: Hi Tony, I'm unable to find what you refer to, could you please refer more precise? 

In the referenced standard I can only find "20%" and "5%" tolerances under section "3.4.2.1 Solder Paste Stencil" and "7.4.1 Wave Soldering" which don't have anything to do with the pitch and dimension tolerances, what I can see.

Comment: Is this for manual or auto-insertion?

Comment: The components is manually placed/inserted on the PCB before wave soldering.